# Oracle nvl need to insert null into a number field

Tags: oracle, nvl

This is a fallback script for a delete script i am running. Here is the query i am using to generate the insert statements.

```
select 'insert into remark_element(ELEMENTID, 
                                   REMARKID, 
                                   VALUE, 
                                   POSITION, 
                                   INFO_TYPE, 
                                   SCRIPTID)
                           values('||elementid||',
                                  '||remarkid||',
                                '''||nvl(value,'null')||''',
                                  '||position||',
                                  '||nvl(info_type,null)||',
                                  '||nvl(scriptid,null)||''||')' 
                          from remark_element 
                          where elementid in(....
```

This is the result of that query:

```
insert into remark_element(ELEMENTID,
                           REMARKID, 
                           VALUE, 
                           POSITION, 
                           INFO_TYPE, 
                           SCRIPTID)     
                    values(29650520,
                           20263860,
                          '0/877-426-6251-A',
                           1,,);
```

running this gives ORA-00936: missing expression because of the empty info_type and scriptid, fields, which are both numbers and are allowed to be nullable. i need the generated query to say

```
insert into remark_element(ELEMENTID, 
                           REMARKID, 
                           VALUE, 
                           POSITION, 
                           INFO_TYPE, 
                           SCRIPTID) 
                    values(29650520,
                           20263860,
                          '0/877-426-6251-A',
                           1,
                           null,
                           null);
```

when info_type and scriptid are null. i have tried doing nvl(info_type,'null') but get ORA-01722: invalid number for trying to put a string into a number field. how can i manipulate this to return as null instead of ,, when the info_type or scriptid is null

Answer (score 2):

Since your output is ultimately a string, just have both `nvl` arguments be a string by using `to_char` to cast your column to a string:

```
nvl(to_char(info_type), 'null')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating code.  I prefer to use `coalesce()`, because it is ANSI standard.  The second argument should be the string `'null'` rather than the constant `null`.

```
select 'insert into remark_element(ELEMENTID, REMARKID, VALUE, POSITION, INFO_TYPE, SCRIPTID) values('||elementid || ',' || remarkid || ',''' || nvl(value,'null') || ''',' ||position||',' ||
coalesce(cast(info_type as varchar2(255)), 'null') || ',' || coalesce(cast(scriptid as varchar2(255)), 'null') || ''||')'
from remark_element where elementid in(....
```

Comment: coalesce returns the first non null expression in the list, so we still have the same issue that we had of returning a string when oracle is expecting a number. i ran your query and still got the same error

Comment: slightly different error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Comment: @Gordon, both `NVL` and `coalesce` are strict about data types; you cannot compare a `NUMBER` column with a `CHAR` literal (that cannot be implicitly cast to a `NUMBER`) like that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @sstan's answer is to use the [`decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions042.htm) function which is not as sensitive as `NVL` or `coalesce` when it comes to mixing different data types:

```
decode(info_type, null, 'null', info_type)
```

The above statement inspects the value of `info_type` and returns `'null'` if the value was `null`; otherwise the inspected value itself is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, work for me:

```
select 'insert into remark_element(ELEMENTID, REMARKID, VALUE, POSITION, INFO_TYPE, SCRIPTID) values('||elementid||','||remarkid||','''||nvl(value,'null')||''','||position||','||
nvl(info_type,'null')||','||nvl(scriptid,'null')||''||')' from remark_element where elementid = 29650520
```

When you are executing the query and the Oracle find **null** the result is nothing, but if use 'null', it will be considered like a string.

So, replace `(info_type,null)` for `(info_type,'null')`, with quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be like this:

```
select 'insert into remark_element(ELEMENTID, 
                               REMARKID, 
                               VALUE, 
                               POSITION, 
                               INFO_TYPE, 
                               SCRIPTID)
                       values('||elementid||',
                              '||remarkid||',
                              '||nvl2(value,''''||value||'''','null')||',
                              '||position||',
                              '||nvl2(info_type,to_char(info_type), 'null')||',
                              '||nvl2(scriptid,to_char(scriptid), 'null')||')' 
                      from remark_element 
                      where elementid in(....
```

Comment: This will fail with `ORA-01722: invalid number` because the second and third input argument of `NVL2` have different data types. You need to either use `decode` or wrap the column within `to_char()` (`nvl2(info_type, to_char(info_type), 'null')`).